# Html5 main tag and tree structure concerning

Tags: html, program-entry-point

The **HTML `<main>` element** represents the dominant content of the `<body>` of a document, portion of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document, or the central functionality of an application. [Quote Mozilla Dev.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

### Questions in my mind

**#1**

*Do we support the same feature if we add a "role" to the "div" tag later? And the same special cases apply?*

```
<div role="main"> == <main> ?
```

**#2**

**The content of a `<main>` element should be unique to the document. Content that is repeated across a set of documents or document sections such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms should not be included unless the search form is the main function of the page.. [Quote Mozilla Dev.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)**

*It really is a special situation or too much of a relative exceptional situation. A relative explanation.*

*The only concrete thing I understand (Tree Structure)*

**eg. wrong usage**

```
<header>..</header>
<article>
    <main></main>
</article>
<aside>..</aside>
<footer></footer>
```

**eg. correct use**

```
<header>..</header>
<main>
    <article>..</article>
</main>
<aside>..</aside>
<footer></footer>
```

*So actually the question in my mind is starting right here.*

```
    <header>..</header>
    <main>
        <article>
             <form>
                 <input type="text" name="user_name" />
                 ....
                 ....
             </form>
        </article>
    </main>
    <aside>..</aside>
    <footer></footer>
```

*Now that I use the form element after the main tag, is this an incorrect use?*

**Screenshot of my project page tree**
[image: Screenshot of my project page tree]

This a landing page, and the form a register action "Special for this document". So now googlebot read it for collective website form "Like a search form", finally created a negative scenario?

I mean is that the content of the main tag should only be composed of pure text? Sources are a complete mystery!

### If we give a much more specific example

***Youtube***

Youtube using `role="main"`

[image]

**My review:** Tag including, the search form and navigation menu. Because search form main characteristic for youtube...

### As a result of this:

> For example, If I have a search engine page and I am including the search form after the main tag;
>
> **Scenario 1**: 
>   I made a violation of the rules in a strict manner and the undesired motion was negatively affected by the seo, the tree making is wrong.
>
> **Scenario 2**:
>   It is not an obvious violation of the rules, but an undesirable aspect of the advice. Googlebot etc. it will not be a negative situation for seo because it can not detect whether the violation is valid (because it is affecting the main content, perhaps using it).

Is there any good idea or technical support?

Answer (score 0):

Like most HTML semantics, a good dose of pragmatism is helpful. Fragmentation of the main role in WAI-ARIA is possible, but strongly disliked and therefore not valid for the `<main>` element. What that means is that the main element should be the minimal container to hold everything that is the principal content of the page. If that incidentally contains things that would be placed outside the main element if the tree structure permitted it, that should just be accepted as a necessary deviation from the ideal.